# StringWriter or StringBuilder

Tags: .net, stringbuilder, stringwriter

What is the difference between `StringWriter` and `StringBuilder` and when should I use one or the other?

Answer (score 103):

I don't think any of the existing answers really answer the question. The actual relationship between the two classes is an example of [the adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

`StringWriter` implements all its `Write...` methods by forwarding on to an instance of `StringBuilder` that it stores in a field. This is not merely an internal detail, because `StringWriter` has a public method [GetStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.getstringbuilder.aspx) that returns the internal string builder, and also [a constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hshta06.aspx) that allows you to pass in an existing `StringBuilder`.

So `StringWriter` is an adaptor that allows `StringBuilder` to be used as a target by code that expects to work with a `TextWriter`. In terms of basic behaviour there is clearly nothing to choose between them... unless you can measure the overhead of forwarding the calls, in which case `StringWriter` is slightly slower, but that seems very unlikely to be significant.

So why didn't they make `StringBuilder` implement `TextWriter` directly? This is a grey area, because the intention behind an interface is not necessarily always clear at first glance.

`TextWriter` is *very nearly* an interface to something that accepts a stream of characters. But it has an additional wrinkle: a property called [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.encoding.aspx). This implies that `TextWriter` is an interface to something that accepts a stream of characters *and also converts them into bytes*.

This is a useless vestige in `StringWriter` because it performs no encoding. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.encoding.aspx) says:

> This property is necessary for some XML scenarios where a header must
>   be written containing the encoding used by the StringWriter. This
>   allows the XML code to consume an arbitrary StringWriter and generate
>   the correct XML header.

But that can't be right, because there is no way for us to specify the value of `Encoding` for `StringWriter`. The property always has the value `UnicodeEncoding`. Consequently any code that examined this property to build an XML header into would always say `utf-16`. For example:

```
var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
    xDocument.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
```

That produces the header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

What if you used [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375) to write your XML string to a file? By default, you'd then have a `utf-8` file with a `utf-16` header.

In such scenarios it would be safer to use `StreamWriter`, and construct it with a file path, or a `FileStream`, or if you want to examine the data then use a `MemoryStream` and so [obtain an array of bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx). All these combinations would ensure that the encoding to bytes and the header generation were being guided by the same `Encoding` value in your `StreamWriter`.

The aim of the `Encoding` property was to allow generators of character streams to include accurate information about the encoding into the character stream itself (such as in the XML example; other examples include email headers, and so on).

But by introducing `StringWriter`, that link between content generation and encoding is broken, and so such automatic mechanisms stop working and become potentially error prone.

Nevertheless, `StringWriter` is a useful adaptor if you are careful, i.e. you understand that your content generation code should not depend on the meaningless value of the `Encoding` property. But that kind of caveat is commonly associated with the adaptor pattern. It's often a sort of hack to allow you to fit a square-ish-but-almost round peg into a round hole.

Comment: You can create a derived `StringWriter` type which [uses a different encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3862106/1062614).

Answer (score 61):

[`StringWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx) derives from [`TextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx), which allows various classes to write text without caring where it's going. In the case of `StringWriter`, the output is just into memory. You would use this if you're calling an API which needs a `TextWriter` but you only want to build up results in memory.

[`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) is essentially a buffer which allows you to perform multiple operations (typically appends) to a "logical string" without creating a new string object each time. You would use this to construct a string in multiple operations.

Answer (score 10):

Building on the previous (good) answers, `StringWriter` is actually much more versatile than `StringBuilder`, providing lots of overloads.

For example:

While `StringBuilder` only accepts a string or nothing for `AppendLine`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("A string");
```

`StringWriter` can take a string format directly

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
sw.WriteLine("A formatted string {0}", DateTime.Now);
```

With `StringBuilder`, one must do this (or use `string.Format`, or `$""`)

```
sb.AppendFormat("A formatted string {0}", DateTime.Now);
sb.AppendLine();
```

Not do or die stuff, but still a difference.

Answer (score 3):

The `StringBuilder` class is basically a mutable string, a helper class to *construct* an immutable string. The `StringWriter` is built on top to add more convenience functions for string formatting.

Answer (score 2):

A [`StringWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx) is used to write text to <del>a file</del> memory and a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) is used to append strings together in a memory-efficient manner.

Answer (score -2):

`StringBuilder` and `StringReader` are used to improve performance in different situations.
**Use** `StringBuilder` to improve performance on string manipulation such as concatenation, modifying string repeatedly.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// Generate 10 random numbers and store in sb.
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sb.Append(rnd.Next().ToString("N5"));
}
Console.WriteLine("The original string:");
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

// Decrease each number by one.
for (int ctr = 0; ctr < sb.Length; ctr++)
{
    if (Char.GetUnicodeCategory(sb[ctr]) == System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber)
    {
        int number = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(sb[ctr]);
        number--;
        if (number < 0)
            number = 9;

        sb[ctr] = number.ToString()[0];
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("\nThe new string:");
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

**Use** `StringReader` to parse a large amount of text in separate lines and minimize memory use while processing data. See next example where ReadLine method on StringReader simply scans for the next newline starting at the current postion, and then return a sbstring based on the field string.

```
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader("input.txt"))
{
    // Loop over the lines in the string or txt file.
    int count = 0;
    string line;
    while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        count++;
        Console.WriteLine("Line {0}: {1}", count, line);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how anyone could have upvoted this answer; the OP's question is about `StringWriter` not `StringReader`.