# String assembly by StringBuilder vs StringWriter and PrintWriter

Tags: java

I recently encountered an idiom I haven't seen before: string assembly by `StringWriter` and `PrintWriter`.  I mean, I know how to use them, but I've always used `StringBuilder`.  Is there a concrete reason for preferring one over the other?  The `StringBuilder` method seems much more natural to me, but is it just style?

I've looked at several questions here (including this one which comes closest: [StringWriter or StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602279/stringwriter-or-stringbuilder) ), but none in which the answers actually address the question of whether there's a reason to prefer one over the other for simple string assembly.

This is the idiom I've seen and used many many times: string assembly by StringBuilder:

```
public static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
public String viaStringBuilder () {
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   builder.append("first thing").append(newline);  // NOTE: avoid doing builder.append("first thing" + newline);
   builder.append("second thing").append(newline);
   // ... several things
   builder.append("last thing").append(newline);
   return builder.toString();
}
```

And this is the new idiom: string assembly by StringWriter and PrintWriter:

```
public String viaWriters() {
   StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
   PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
   printWriter.println("first thing");
   printWriter.println("second thing");
   // ... several things
   printWriter.println("last thing");
   printWriter.flush();
   printWriter.close();
   return stringWriter.toString();
}
```

**Edit** It appears that there is no *concrete* reason to prefer one over the other, so I've accepted the answer which best matches my understanding, and +1ed all the other answers.  In addition, I posted an answer of my own, giving the results of the benchmarking I ran, in response to one of the answers. Thanks to all.

**Edit again** It turns out that there *is* a concrete reason to prefer one (specifically the StringBuilder) over the other. What I missed the first time was the addition of the newline.  When you add a newline (as above, as a separate append), it's slightly faster - not hugely, but coupled with the clarity of intent, it's definitely better. See my answer below for the improved timings.

Comment: You should not use `builder.append("first thing" + newline)`. The problem is that there's an extra String allocation which is not needed (it first creates "first thing\n" and then copies the string data to the builder). Instead, do it like this: `builder.append("first thing").append(newline)`. This directly copies `"first thing"` to the builder and then `newline`. Of couse, StringBuilder should only be used if the number of things is not constant (e.g. it's in a loop), javac already optimizes `"a" + "b" + "c"` into `new StringBuilder().append("a").append("b").append("c").toString()`.

Comment: @robinst Apologies for the very slow response. I just revisited this question and noticed your comment.  Excellent point, and I've redone my test. See edits.

Comment: `Throwable.printStackTrace()` requires a writer.

Comment: I am surprised that the OP accepted answer for 'stylistic' reasons. Alan Moore's explanation is more than satisfactory. I have actually come across a scenario where i was forced to use StringWriter because the API (third party API) expects Writer instance and i just wanted to write the contents to the string rather than file/stdout. It really doesn't matter if StringWriter internally uses Stringbuffer/Stringbuilder as long as the writer is not shared with multiple threads.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Stylistically, the `StringBuilder` approach is cleaner.  It is fewer lines of code and is using a class that was specifically designed for the purpose of building strings.

The other consideration is which is more efficient.  The correct way to answer that would be to benchmark the alternatives, but (based on the source code) I would *expect* `StringBuilder` to be faster.

A `StringWriter` uses a `StringBuffer` (rather than a `StringBuilder`) under the hood to hold the characters written to the "stream".  Thus using a `StringWriter` for string assembly is going to incur `StringBuffer`'s synchronization overhead, whether your application needs it or not.  But if your application *does* need the synchronization, then you should consider using a `StringBuffer` directly.

---

CPerkins has done some benchmarking (see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2981146/139985)) and his results align with my intuition.  They say that the difference between optimal `StringBuilder` vs `StringWriter` is ~5% which is likely to be insignificant for a *typical* application<sup>1</sup>.  However, it is nice to know that the "style" and "performance" criteria are giving the same answer!

<sup>1 - While a typical application doesn't spend most of its time assembling strings, there are exceptions.  However, one should not spend time optimizing this kind of thing based purely on guesswork.  Profile your code first.</sup>

Answer (score 43):

`StringWriter` is what you use when when you want to write to a string, but you're working with an API that expects a `Writer` or a `Stream`.  It's not an alternative, it's a compromise: you use `StringWriter` only when you have to.

Comment: Thanks, and that does make sense, but I've found this widely used in a codebase written by a set of very smart people - actually, on average, they seem to be the smartest I've ever worked with.  So I'm looking for reasons they might have done it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to this question. I have actually come across a scenario where i was forced to use StringWriter because the API (third party API) expects Writer instance and  i just wanted to write the contents to the string rather than file/stdout.@Alan simply nailed it when he said "You use StringWriter  when you have to".

Comment: I've come across a scenario where I was forced to use `StringWriter` because the API _of_ _the_ `java.lang.Throwable` _class_ does not have any methods that receive a `StringBuilder` as an argument when the stack trace of an exception has to be printed (there are only methods that accept a [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28java.io.PrintStream%29) or [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28java.io.PrintWriter%29)).

Comment: To be clear, it's a compromise because you wanted to use a StringBuilder (assuming no multiple threads involved) which would have been more clean and efficient.

Answer (score 21):

Okay, since the answers seem to stress the stylistic reasons for preferring one over the other, I decided to gen up a timing test.

**Edit**: Following robinst's comment above, I now have three methods: one which does PrintWriter(StringWriter)-style appending, and two which use StringBuilder: one with the append of the newline inside the append (as in the original: `builder.append(thing + newline);`), and the other does a separate append (as above: `builder.append(thing).append(newline);`).

I followed my usual benchmarking scheme: call the methods several (1000 in this case) times first to give the optimizer time to warm up, then call each a large number of times (100,000 in this case) in alternating sequence, so that any changes in the workstation's runtime environment are more fairly distributed, and run the test itself several times and average the results.

Oh, and of course the number of lines created and the length of the lines is randomized but held to be the same for each pair of calls, because I wanted to avoid any possible effects of buffer size or line size on the results.

The code for this is here: http://pastebin.com/vtZFzuds

Note: I have not yet updated the pastebin code to reflect the new test.

**TL,DR?**  The average results for 100,000 calls to each method are quite close:

- 0.11908 ms per call using StringBuilder (+newline inside the paren)
- 0.10201 ms per call using StringBuilder (newline as a separate append)
- 0.10803 ms per call using PrintWriter(StringWriter)

That's so close that the timing is nearly irrelevant to me, so I'm going to continue doing things the way I always did: StringBuilder(with separate append), for stylistic reasons.  Of course, while working in this established and mature codebase, I'll mostly keep to the existing conventions, in order to minimize surprise.

Comment: Results are not surprising. Assuming that any particular call to `write(...)` on `StringWriter` simply executes one matching call to `append(...)` on the internal `StringBuilder`, this is exactly the kind of boilerplate that the Java JIT is designed to optimize away.

Comment: @jdmichal `StringWriter` uses a **`StringBuffer`**, which is the `synchronized` alternative to the `StringBuilder`. So the JIT also needs to removed unnecessary locks - which it is much better at doing these days than it used to be. Still, the problem is non-trivial and the similarity if performance is perhaps a little more surprising that you might think...

Comment: In relative terms, your test shows StringWriter to be **6%** slower than StringBuilder (because it uses a synchronized StringBuffer internally and because of its own overhead), while the bad newline append is **17%** slower than correct StringBuilder usage. Granted, the time taken is not twice or more, but I wouldn't say "irrelevant", especially if you're handling large amounts of data. Also, Hello almost 10 year old thread :-)

Answer (score 16):

**Writers**
- PrintWriter  writes to a stream. It does weird things like suppressing IOExceptions. System.out is one of these.
- StringWriter is a Writer that writes to a StringBuffer (similar to ByteArrayOutputStream for OutputStreams)

**StringBuilder**
- and of course StringBuilder is what you want if you are simply want to constructs strings in memory.

**Conclusion**

Writers by design are meant to push character data out a stream (usually to a file or through a connection) so being able to use Writers to simply assemble strings seems to be a bit of a side effect.

StringBuilder (and its synchronized sibling StringBuffer)  are *designed* to assemble strings (read string bashing).  If you look at the [StringBuilder API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) you can see thatnot only can you do vanilla appending but also replace, reverse, insert etc.  StringBuilder is your String construction friend.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I understand what they each do.  But I've come across this new (to me) idiom in code written by some very smart people, and I'm wondering if they had a good reason to prefer it.

Comment: OK, no problem I have added a conclusion section to the answer.

Comment: So your reason is basically stylistic: it relies on the notion that StringBuilder's **intention** is to manipulate strings, while the ability to do so with the Writers is a side effect.

Answer (score 7):

I see two advantages of the PrintWriter method:
(1) You don't have to add " + newline" at the end of every single line, which actually results in shorter code if you have a lot of writing to do.
(2) You don't have to call System.getProperty(); you let the PrintWriter worry about what the newline character should be.

Comment: Good thoughts.  I'm not as worried about having to call `System.getProperty()`, as it's a one-time cost which amortizes to zero if, as you say, you're writing a lot of code.  

Definitely a good point about having to `+ newline` with `StringBuilder`, though.

Answer (score 2):

in this link : http://nohack.eingenetzt.com/java/java-stringwriter-vs-stringbuilder
the author shows that the StringWriter is even slightly faster than the StringBuilder.and also said : "So when bigger amounts of data come into play the StringWriter clearly shows its superiority in performance over the StringBuilder."

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the implementation of StringWriter in JDK 11, it uses a `StringBuffer` underneath. StringBuffer is a synchronized version of StringBuilder, as described in [this question on StringBuilder vs. StringBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/difference-between-stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer)

Considering this, StringBuilder can be slightly faster. So if you are writing performance-sensitive code, prefer StringBuilder unless you need synchronization.

In my case, I had to choose between using a StringBuilder or a StringWriter as an `Appendable`, and I did not need the synchronization of StringWriter/StringBuffer.

To summarize:

- StringBuilder - unsynchronized in-memory appending
- StringBuffer - synchronized in-memory appending
- StringWriter - wraps StringBuffer, also extends Writer