# Optimize BufferedReader readLine() operations

Tags: java, bufferedreader, stringbuilder

I am trying to read a response from server using `HttpsURLConnection`.

```
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader((InputStream) con.getContent());
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(in);

    String line;
    StringBuilder response=new StringBuilder();
    long st=System.nanoTime();

    while ((line =buff.readLine())!= null) {
        response=response.append(line +"\n");

    } 

    long et=System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("resp process time: "+((et-st))+" ns");
    return response.toString();
}
```

Currently, it takes approximately 450 ms to read the entire response consisting  about 80000 characters( 1100 lines).

Output: resp process time: 435272240 ns

Would it be possible to optimize this code further to reduce processing time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: how to read BufferedReader faster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666748/java-how-to-read-bufferedreader-faster)

Comment: @OSryx Not exactly a duplicate, as this one here uses a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

You create an unnecessary temporary string `line + "\n"`. You can avoid this.

```
while ((line = buff.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(line).append('\n');
}
```

You can also avoid the BufferedReader (no need to scan the input for linebreaks).

```
InputStreamReader in = ...
char buffer[] = new char[8192];
int count;
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
    response.append(buffer, 0, count);
```

Comment: +1 for the part where you use a char[] instead of `BufferedReader`. I personally prefer this option if you are not doing any processing on each line. Might cause problems if input size is too large :P

Comment: size of the response from server is not fixed and can differ greatly with each request, so this solution is correct but not appropriate for this particular scenario

Comment: @Akki: BufferedReader also has a default buffer of 8192 chars, so memory characteristics are the same for both solutions. Of course, if the response sends a content-length header and encoding you could estimate the size of response buffer and any temporary buffer for copying.